# How to give chart title to a chart in Python-pptx chart in Chart Area(Not the slide title)

Tags: python, python-3.x, charts, python-pptx

I am trying to add text to chart title in chart area in a PPT Slide(Not the slide title).I have http://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev/analysis/cht-chart-title.html this link if any text can be added to my chart but I couldn't find the solution.Here is my,

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc
#import pptx as ppt 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pptx import Presentation
from pptx.chart.data import ChartData
from pptx.chart.data import XyChartData
from pptx.enum.chart import XL_CHART_TYPE
from pptx.util import Inches,Pt
from pptx.enum.chart import XL_LABEL_POSITION
from pptx.dml.color import RGBColor
from pptx.dml import fill
from pptx.chart.chart import ChartTitle
from pptx.chart.chart import Chart



cnxn = pyodbc.connect("Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};"
                        "Server=SNAME;"
                        "Database=DNAME;"
                        "Trusted_Connection=yes;")
AvgResponseTimequery = 'EXEC [SLA].[MONTHWISEREPORT]'
df=pd.read_sql(sql=AvgResponseTimequery,con=cnxn)
#df




getprs = Presentation('D:\SLA Pyth\hubiC-06-20-2017 1_10_55\SLAPerformance.pptx')
slide = getprs.slides.add_slide(getprs.slide_layouts[5])
slide.shapes.title.text = 'Key Performance KPIs'

chart_data = ChartData()
chart_data.categories = df['Month'].values.tolist()
chart_data.add_series('Average Report Response time(Seconds)', tuple(df['Avg Response Time']))
x, y, cx, cy = Inches(0.5), Inches(2), Inches(9), Inches(3)

chart=slide.shapes.add_chart(
    XL_CHART_TYPE.COLUMN_CLUSTERED, x, y, cx, cy, chart_data
).chart

#chart.has_title = True
#Chart.chart_title = "Response Time in Seconds"  #Tried to add text here, I didnt get any error though
#ChartTitle.has_text_frame = True


chart.has_title = True
chart.chart_title = "Response Time in Seconds"
# Check the has_text_frame property of this chart's chart_title:
print(chart.has_text_frame)



plot = chart.plots[0]
plot.has_data_labels = True
data_labels = plot.data_labels

chart.series[0].format.fill.solid()
chart.series[0].format.fill.fore_color.rgb = RGBColor(46, 125, 137)

getprs.save('D:\SLA REPORT MONTH WISE\SALReport1.pptx')
```

Comment: Have you tried the solution below?

Comment: I am getting error, ; 'str' object has no attribute 'has_text_frame'

Comment: try `print(chart.has_text_frame)`

Comment: Tried and got this error : 'Chart' object has no attribute 'has_text_frame'

Comment: OK hold on, let me install this package.

Comment: That print statement is really not necessary, though, can you confirm that the output PPTX file contains a chart title?

Comment: Ya it has it. I am getting as 'Chart Title' but am expecting my title as 'Average Report Response time(Seconds)'

Comment: Can you update your question to show the code as you're currently using?

Comment: @DavidZemens added my code.

Comment: OK please refer to my revised answer

Comment: I got this error ; ---> 48 chart.chart_title.has_text_frame=True
     49 chart.chart_title.text_frame.text='Response Time in Seconds'
     50 

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'has_text_frame'..
Am i missing any module?

Comment: basically the error is : 'str' object has no attribute 'has_text_frame'

Comment: Unable to replicate the error in python 2.7 with latest pptx package.

Comment: `chart.chart_title` should not be an instance of `str` it should be an instance of `pptx.chart.chart.ChartTitle object`

Comment: I am using python 3.6 with latest pptx package.

Comment: The link you send is not *documentation* it's a proposed change to the API from a previous version. Are you sure you are using pptx 0.6.6?  The documentation indicates that *Currently python-pptx requires Python 2.6, 2.7, 3.3 or 3.4.* so it might not work with 3.6...

Comment: Here is dox for 0.6.6 http://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/chart.html#pptx.chart.chart.ChartTitle

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Possible typo, case-sensitivity. When you do `Chart.chart_title` you're referring to the *class* `Chart` not your `chart` object. Likewise, `ChartTitle.has_text_frame` refers to the *class* `ChartTitle` not your `chart`!

After installing this pptx package and debugging (I got error on `chart.has_title`, etc.), I think you need:

```
chart.chart_title.has_text_frame=True
chart.chart_title.text_frame.text='Response Time in Seconds'
```

NOTE: You don't need this line:

```
chart.chart_title.has_text_frame=True
```

Setting the `text_frame.text` will be sufficient.

Here is exact code I used to test. First, create a new presentation with only 1 slide. Remove all shapes/placeholders from that slide and insert 1 chart only. Save & close the presentation.

```
from pptx import Presentation
from pptx.chart.data import ChartData
from pptx.chart.data import XyChartData
from pptx.enum.chart import XL_CHART_TYPE
from pptx.util import Inches,Pt
from pptx.enum.chart import XL_LABEL_POSITION
from pptx.dml.color import RGBColor
from pptx.dml import fill
from pptx.chart.chart import ChartTitle
from pptx.chart.chart import Chart

file = 'c:\debug\pres.pptx'
pres = Presentation(file)
slide = pres.slides[0]
chart = slide.shapes[0].chart
chart.chart_title.text_frame.text='my new chart title'
pres.save(file)
```

Further, from console, I see these types, indicating that `chart.chart_title` is not an instance of `str` object, etc:

```
>>> type(chart)
<class 'pptx.chart.chart.Chart'>
>>> type(chart.chart_title)
<class 'pptx.chart.chart.ChartTitle'>
```

Note, [the documentation indicates](http://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/install.html#install):

> Currently python-pptx requires Python 2.6, 2.7, 3.3 or 3.4.

If you are using python 3.6 then perhaps that is why it is not working as expected, it is not supported version of python.

Comment: This is working fine. I am bit puzzled to apply this to my code. I will do it in a short time and let you know.

Comment: Its working fine with python 3.6 too, but the problem is its fine in one system and not performing well in other system and both system have same version of python and pptx.